# create a user ID in java using their names

Tags: java

I need to create a program to read in a user’s name in two bits: first name and surname.  from these two names I need to create a user ID.  The format of the ID is the initial letter from their first name and up to the first 5 characters in their surname?

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: I need to create a program.equals("You need to write the code yourself");

Comment: You do need to do your own homework. You'll never learn to code if you don't. If you get stuck or are having a specific problem, post what code you have written and what the problem is and people can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
String id = name.substring(0,1) + surname.substring(0,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String fName = "Jon";
String lName = "Doe";
String id = fName.charAt(0) + StringUtils.substring(lName, 0, 5);
System.out.println(id);
```

Consider to use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). As you can see in my example, the lenght of String "Doe" is fewer than 5.

Comment: you should add additional check, what if fname or sname is null? :P just kidding...